# Php SimplePie library not working properly

Tags: php

> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in C:\Workspace\htdocs\feedBlurb\processing\simplepie.inc
>   on line 738

this is the error I get when I run the following SimplePie code on my server:

```
<?php
require_once("processing/simplepie.inc");
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url(array('http://feeds2.feedburner.com/CssTricks', 'http://smashingmagazine.com'));
$feed->enable_cache(true);
$feed->set_cache_location('core/cache');
$feed->set_cache_duration(1800);
$feed->init();
$feed->handle_content_type();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<title>Feedblurb</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<h1>Feedblurb</h1>
<?php if($feed->error): ?>
<span id='error'><?php echo $feed->error; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach($feed->get_items() as $item): ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems like all instances of SimplePie don't seem to work on my server.. But I have a WordPress blog which is running SimplePie and that seems to work just fine. My development server is running the latest version of XAMPP. Any ideas?

Comment: Remove the ampersand `&` at line 738

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a [version of SimplePie](https://github.com/simplepie/simplepie/blob/one-dot-two/simplepie.inc) specifically designed to support legacy PHP4 applications, so your modern installation of XAMPP will cause it to cough up deprecation warnings.

You should upgrade to a [newer version of SimplePie](https://github.com/simplepie/simplepie) which is actively maintained and designed for modern versions of PHP.

If you can't upgrade, you can either fix the error yourself, or configure your server to stop reporting deprecation warnings by changing `error_level` to `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED` in your php.ini:

```
; error_reporting
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
;   Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED

error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Comment: Okay cool... I just changed the error reporting. Will that stop error reporting but still keep the application from running?